# Socket Printing issues: PHP/Toshiba B-SA4TM

Tags: php, sockets, encoding, printing

we're having this toshiba barcode printer. I'm not sure whether this problem is hardware or php related.

When we send a ° (degree-sign) it prints a € (euro-sign).

I also tried brute-forcing iconv():

```
$a = array("UTF-8", "ASCII", "Windows-1252", "ISO-8859-15", "ISO-8859-1", "ISO-8859-6", "CP1256", "cp850");
foreach ($a as $enc){
if (@fputs($fp, iconv('UTF-8', $enc, $r)) === false) { ...and so on
```

without any success!

Is anyone familiar with this issue who can help me solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem had been two fold:

1. The font we were using isn't capable of the degree sign
2. The codepage of the printer had to be switched to utf-8